# Why C# and Perl's regex result is different?

Tags: c#, regex, perl

Following C# code is I recreated perl code to C#.
It was same regex but its result is different.
Perl code was captured "a" but C# code was captured "apple".
What makes it different?

C# code

```
string word = Regex.Replace("apple", "(?<C>a(?=pple)|b(?=anana)|c(?=herry))", "${C}");

Console.WriteLine("fruit\'s initial: {0}", word); // result: "fruit's initial: apple"
```

Perl code

```
my $word = 'apple';

if ($word =~ /(?<C>a(?=pple)|b(?=anana)|c(?=herry))/) {
print "fruit\'s initial: $+{C}"; // result: "fruit's initial: a"
}
```

Comment: Well, in Perl you *matched and captured*  `a`, and then printed it. In C#, you replaced `a` with `a` and certainly got `apple` unchanged.

Comment: Related info: In this particular example, you're not performing the same operation with both languages, so you get different results. But in broader terms, you may expect differences between different regex engines. Most regex features overlap between .NET and Perl, but each of these *flavors* also has its own features (ie Perl has recursion, .NET has variable-length lookbehind). See [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for a comparison between regex flavors. If you need something that mimics the Perl flavor in .NET, see my profile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Perl, you matched and captured the first `a` followed with `pple` into Group "C", and then printed it. In C#, you replaced `a` followed with `pple` with `a` and got `apple` unchanged as a result.

Use matching instead:

```
var m = Regex.Match("apple", "(?<C>a(?=pple)|b(?=anana)|c(?=herry))");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("fruit\'s initial: {0}", m.Groups["C"].Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/uDjcap).

Here, the regex match is assigned to the `m` variable. If the match occurs (`if (m.Success)`), you may get Group "C" value using `m.Groups["C"].Value`.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Conversely, the Perl equivalent of the OP's C# code is `my $word = "apple" =~ s/(?<C>a(?=pple)|b(?=anana)|c(?=herry))/$+{C}/gr;`

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I also thought about adding a similar comment, just I see this sort of pointless to replace a value with itself :).